# How can I find the second latest time a condition was met in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to find the amount of bars between the last time the condition was met and the second to last time the condition was met. With this code, I have successfully found the amount of time since the condition was met latest but I get a value of 0 when trying to find the amount of time between

```
//@version=5
condition = ta.cross(deliveryVolumePercentage, 60)
bars_since = int(ta.barssince(condition))
bars_since1 = (ta.barssince(condition))[bars_since]

plot(bars_since, title = "1")
plot(bars_since1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple kept, something like this could work as you want:

```
//@version=5
...
condition = ta.cross(deliveryVolumePercentage, 60)
var int conditionLastTrueOnBar = na
bars_since = ta.barssince(condition)

// updated condition found
if nz(conditionLastTrueOnBar) != bar_index - bars_since
    wasTrueOnBar = bar_index - bars_since
    diffBetween2InBars = wasTrueOnBar - nz(conditionLastTrueOnBar)
    // do some logic

    // update last time for the next time
    conditionLastTrueOnBar := wasTrueOnBar
...
```

Comment: Hey elod008
After applying this script to my indicator I do not know how to plot diffBetween2InBars (new to pine script). Further help would be much appreciated.
Thanks, Dev